# Mathematical models of dynamic algorithmic processes

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics, ontology

This question primarily concerns dynamical or time-dependent phenomena in philosophy and to what extent such heuristic discourse features in more precise mathematical settings.

In order to model dynamical phenomena, whether in set theoretic, categorical, etc. backgrounds, one often uses directed graph structures, e.g. transition system, which of course necessitates a priori knowledge of the possible outputs. Arguably, the a priori vs a posteriori existence of abstract structures is only a psychological distinction, and I'm wondering how one would model this psychological phenomena mathematically.

To be more precise, suppose we are constructing a formal system within a fixed background meta-theory. In other words, everything we use to construct the system must exist in the meta-theory a priori. Often, one observes dynamical processes built within a formal system which allows the user to generate new strings within the system on demand only beginning with primitives, without necessitating all pre-generated strings to be built into the formal system a priori.

1) Do all such possible output strings as a result of some built-in algorithmic process in the formal system, necessarily exist a priori in the meta-theory itself?

2) If so, is it accurate that a naive psychological analogy be that the human brain plays the role of the formal system which undergoes a dynamical procedure learning more strings and that the meta-theory contain the brain and some external stimuli which in some sense contains all the possible strings?

3) It seems that many finitist responses to constructing a formal system with arbitrarily many symbols are to have an in-built procedure within the formal system which generates new symbols on demand. (I am referring to the stronger finitist stance of objecting even to an algorithmic infinite sequence of symbols). But then, given the above considerations, wouldn't all such symbols necessarily be contained in the meta-theory itself, thus violating the objection to having infinitely many symbols in the meta-theory to begin with?

4) If the above is true, it seems that one necessitates an infinite meta-theory to model a finitist theory. This seems to correlate with the incompleteness theorems in that most of the time, weaker systems cannot prove consistency of stronger systems. Can the correlation between this consistency no-go theorem and the above considerations be made more precise?

Please let me know what I am missing if the above are incorrect due to a misunderstanding in the meta-theory/theory relationship and the definition of such algorithms/procedures.

Comment: Formal systems are not constructed within a meta-theory, fixed or otherwise, natural language suffices to formulate the rules. Meta-theory is usually developed afterwards to study what goes on in the formal system, but one has no need for it to follow the rules themselves. So even if outputs of algorithms are "contained" in meta-theory, they do not "pre-exist" (or even "exist" at all, for nominalists), and strict finitists reject much of model theory anyway as platonistic.

Comment: To clarify, by meta-theory, I just mean any background theory with which one sets up and describes a formal system. So in this case, it would be natural language along with some basic assumptions, such as it's sensible to talk about collections of strings and they exist, etc. Maybe it's due to my training as a mathematician in which we always work within some domain of discourse, universe of sets, category, etc. but I'm confused by certain terminology in the setup of first order logic. For reference, c.f. for example the discussion in Tourlakis vol 1 Logic, pp 10-12.

Comment: My main confusions are about the precise meaning of "working within a theory/formal system" and having a "procedure to generate objects variables on demand." Namely, what am I missing when I assume that the object variables and everything we use to construct the formal system necessarily exist a priori within the meta-theory? I have no issue with assuming existence of certain primitives such as symbols, finite sets, etc., but I'm confused with how they do not have to exist a priori in the meta theory.

Comment: Aren't we implicitly assuming it's sensible to talk about such structures in the first place before we use it to construct the formal system? Ultimately, I'm assuming this is probably a philosophical question which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: The word "implicitly" is so often abused. We spend a long time analyzing a thing into conceptual pieces, and then declare that it was all there from the start, "implicitly". No, we do not "assume implicitly" that it is sensible to talk about X to use X. Nor do we have to, or we won't be able to start using anything due to definitional regress. We still do not know if arithmetic is consistent, but even if it is not, as Wittgenstein said, "*it could render very good service; and it would be better for us to modify our concepts than to say that it really not yet have been a proper arithmetic*".

Comment: Okay, in other words, it is sensible to talk about and develop a formal system and the meta-theory simultaneously? In other words, you're saying emphatically that we do not have to work in some fixed background? I suppose I always thought implicitly that the meta-theory had to come before the theory in some sense, such as the external stimuli which leads us to construct certain thoughts. In addition to clarify, it is true that even those who reject existence of abstract objects, at least acknowledge existence of symbols and finite strings right?

Comment: It is sensible not to develop meta-theory at all, although it is beneficial at some point. People made a good use of arithmetic and geometry long before any formal rules were laid down, let alone meta-theories (plural) developed. History of math is a history of unfixed background where multiple meta-interpretations of the same practice rise, morph and fall, and help expand it in various, sometimes mutually exclusive ways (calculus is a typical example). Even when it comes to symbols and strings, how the import of their use is parsed differs between Brouwer, Hilbert and Wittgenstein, say.

Comment: Great, thanks, I think I understand now. It seems easy to forget that at the very bottom, there are many different philosophical stances and different interpretations of  mathematical foundations stemming from everyday intuition, as opposed to working with everyday mathematics. I might ask elsewhere as well just to see if there are any additional perspectives/details I'm missing.

Comment: I do have one remaining question. Previously, you stated that a priori vs a posteriori construction is only a psychological distinction. However, for example, in the text i cited earlier, the author claims to accommodate finitist stances by introducing a procedure (|-calculation) for the user to generate new symbols on demand. On the other hand, he claims that having a finitely generated, infinite sequence of symbols specified by some algorithm/pattern is insufficient to appease certain finitists while the former is. How would this play with your claim that there is no distinction?

Comment: The reason he seems to cite is that the latter would assume the existence of infinite sets in the meta-theory. Instead he gets around it by either defining the procedure for the user to generate on demand or in vol 2, page 12, he just states that a variable is any object v_i where i is a word of meaningless symbols 0...9, instead of using the term unending sequence of symbols. He cites this as a distinction between finitist and post-Brouwer intuitionist. Could you comment on this?

Comment: This is a typical application of the generation metaphor. A finitist puts herself into a less idealized position where she can not avail herself of an infinite repository of symbols generatable "in principle" *a la* Brouwer, because she wants them examplified by actual tokens. [Ultrafinitists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafinitism) go even further. But, of course, the real disagreement is over which model of the subject, which idealization is more warranted/worthwhile. And they both *are* idealizations, imagined scenarios analyzed abstractly, and hence timeless.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the question of a priori (infinite repository of generable symbols in principle) vs a posteriori (exemplified by actual tokens) existence? If so, how does this fare against your previous comments about how this is only a psychological distinction?

Comment: The actual tokens are only imagined and as *a priori* or timeless as everything else. They only matter to how the metaphor is processed psychologically.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I'm still missing something here since at first, I thought the only difference between these two philosophies were a priori vs a posteriori. Let's take both the infinite repository of symbols and the actual tokens to be timeless and imagined a priori. Then what precisely is the difference between these two philosophical stances? Could you expand a little bit on this point?

Comment: They have conflicting beliefs as to what the practice of mathematics amounts to, or rather *should* amount to, ranging from picking out some objective reality (platonists), to objective potentialities of synthetic intuition (intuitionists), to contingent activities of limited human-like subjects (finitists). The resulting systems have inequivalent sets of rules that seem more relevant/worthwhile to them accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, but my precise confusion can better be phrased as the following. What precisely is the distinction between having an infinite repository of symbols generable "in principle" as opposed to having a procedure to generate symbols on demand and exemplify them via explicit tokens? Evidently, they're both timeless notions, so we can "modalize" the generation procedure into infinity, so what then is the difference? The only thing seems to be that we need infinite sets to talk about the former notion, but after running the procedure to infinity, they seem identical in commitments

Comment: Since the systems they come up with derive different theorems there is a substantive difference, what used to be spelled out as [potential vs actual infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actual_infinity). It is one thing to modalize a process and another to reify its outcome, one thing to allow access to new tokens on demand, and another to allow access to the totality of them fulfilling all conceivable (and not) demands.

Comment: Got it, so in other words, it's essentially the same as working with/without the axiom of infinity? Namely, working internally within zfc which exhibits a model of the peano axioms externally as opposed to working internally within the natural numbers itself? To conclude, can you expand a bit on what you meant by "it's sensible not to develop a meta-theory at all"? I thought that the meta-theory simply consisted of the a priori assumed primitives necessary to construct a formal system, including even natural language.

Comment: Do you mean that in the sense that the first level meta-theory is informal, and in particular, is not some fixed set theoretic structure? Namely, it is impossible to talk about having generative procedures if we are working within a fixed set structure, for instance, since it is necessarily dynamical with respect to new strings that could be generated. And finally, can you comment on the internal/external novelty with respect to the discovery/invention dichotomy or suggest a reference? I don't completely understand that statement.

Comment: Too many questions, I am going to stop at this point.

Comment: Sorry for the the overwhelming amount of questions. Can you just briefly comment on the meta-theory part of the above? I'm completely happy with modalizing a process to infinity and working within it, I've just never seen an aspect of mathematics where we don't work within a fixed structure, but instead talk about a dynamical procedure which doesn't seem to operate within a conventional mathematical structure. I'd also be happy to just look at any reference you happen to have regarding this.

Comment: My question can be concisely formulated as follows. When we say, let M be a model of a first order theory T, before we perform any deduction within M, everything we talk about necessarily exists in M a priori as soon as we assert that it is a model of T. To what extent is that true in generating new strings when working in a formal system or natural language in general?

Comment: I can not figure out the place where your questions come from. I do not see why non-model theorists should care about models at all (they certainly have no need for them when doing the theory itself, except maybe heuristically, but there anything goes), or commit to anything even if they do. A theory is one formal (or informal) game, a model is another, one does not commit by playing with either, or both in concert. I am afraid I am at an end of my usefulness. I'll let others weigh in now, hopefully they can empathize with your concerns more.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, perhaps I'm not articulating my concern sufficiently well, but I'm trying to ask something much more basic, and rather a simple verification of my understanding. I'm not trying to talk about commitments, but only cited a model because it's a conventional set theoretic structure where everything exists a priori. To summarize briefly, maybe I'm just not used to the structures in first order logic, but I would not have thought twice if instead of a string, we said defining a morphism from a subset of the naturals to a finite list of alphabet symbols in natural language.

Comment: In other words, I have no issues with the usual methodology of performing real mathematics in natural language, but I was trying to understand structures in first order logic in terms of conventional mathematical structures. In particular, I understand that for example, we work with an a priori model satisfying axioms which is a set theoretic structure. On the other hand, the notion of a formal system does not seem to conform to a conventional mathematical structure since it allows one to generate new symbols akin to working in natural language.

Comment: However, I also see formal systems defined merely as a subset of a set of well formed strings, which is a set theoretic structure. In conclusion, I'm only trying to seek verification that working in a formal system is completely analogous to natural language and not necessarily restricting to working in a fixed, timeless mathematical structure such as a set or category. I hope it's clearer what I'm trying to get at this time.

Comment: Working in model theory is not at all analogous to working in natural language with vague semantics that does not even matter in most practical cases, and can be fleshed out in many inequivalent ways if one wants it. Perhaps, the problem is that you are trying to squeeze informal practice into Tarskian model theory which was never suitable to be its model, the name notwithstanding. When we work *informally* we work just so, and mathematical structures are of limited use to describe it. But look at [proof-theoretic semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theoretic-semantics/).

Comment: I wasn't trying to claim that model theory is analogous to working natural language, but rather that a model, rather informal or not is usually defined as a set theoretic structure in and of itself. On the other hand, I was trying to ask whether working in a formal system itself is analogous to working in natural language with clearer restriction. The precise operation I'm trying to get at is the notion of being able to generate symbols, but not being able to reference them a priori, which is not adaptable to conventional sets, etc.

Comment: To emphasize a bit more, the main notion I'm trying to identify is the generating new structures within the system itself. This does not seem to be the identical operation within a model for instance, in the sense that every output of such generations necessarily exists within the model at the time of existence of such a model in the first place. However, we talk informally of building structures all the time in natural language. The question is what allows us to do this in formal systems and what are the precise primitive notions necessary for such constructions.

Comment: "What allows us"? The absence or need for "precise primitive notions". Not that it can not be modeled with "mathematical structures", restrictions on what can be referenced, or processes generally, can be modeled with graphs and flow charts easily enough.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm starting to understand. I think ultimately it's due to my rigidity with respect to my training in algebraic geometry, for instance i'm not used to thinking about generative functions of strings. For example, the domain and codomain are always part of the data of a morphism, however here it seems that the actual process carried out by a generative functions takes precedence over specifying the domain and range.

Comment: To put the previous comment in more light, I would never ask what precisely the meta-theory of natural language is, but I think I'm trying to ask what precisely is the kind of structure exhibited by a formal system. If it were simply a collection of alphabets, etc. and not defined as a collection of all possible strings a priori, it does not seem possible to define a notion of a generation of strings which has no clear codomain in this case. And in particular such a definition must have an interpretation in terms of an element internal to that collection.

Comment: For example, in a model of zfc, a function of sets is interpreted as a set structure itself which exists a priori inside the model. I hope my perspective is a bit clearer to you.

Comment: Why don't you take [primitive recursive arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic) as meta-theory, like most finitists do, instead of ZFC?  It does not allow set formation, so "collection of all possible strings" simply can not be expressed. And functions are interpreted very differently, basically as algorithms.

Comment: I think your comment points me towards the source of my confusion. Ultimately, I think it's an internal/external distinction, please let me know if you agree with the following discussion. Usually, when we talk about a model, we specify a precise domain of discourse which satisfies the axioms of some logical system. What I meant by a priori vs a posteriori existence here is that if one were working internally within the model and constructs some structure, then someone looking externally can declare that that output was there from the start.

Comment: On the other hand, no one ever seems to talk about a formal system itself as some fixed domain of discourse established a priori within which we then perform deductions. Thus, I’ve been trying to ask the analogous question for working within a formal system, namely to what extent do the strings generated by working within the system exist to someone external to the logical system. Does this question depend on the meta-theory at hand? Are you essentially claiming that one can remain completely agnostic about this question when working within a formal system?

Comment: And that this is only a meaningful distinction when phrased as questions of syntax vs semantics, in the sense that when we use the logical structures to talk about some existing structure, we really do assume it was there from the start, whereas it is not a useful distinction to make when it comes to syntax? I hope this makes it clear what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: The model you are talking about is a Tarskian model, and "looking externally" through God's eye is only a pretense. It can be useful, but we can only *talk* as if something is there, not *see* it platonistically. There is no real existence even in Tarskian semantics, and we do not assume it other than for psychological comfort. One can instead choose another pretense for working in a formal system, more suitable for human eye, where we can look at generating algorithms only, not their outputs. And yes, one can be oblivious even to such minimal semantics when executing syntax itself.

Comment: Let me try to clarify a bit more about my perspective. I was under the impression that to avoid infinite regress, one necessitates some philosophical commitment at some stage to assume the existence of a model of some formal axioms. Usually, this takes place in an informal meta-theory and a canonical example is where one writes the axioms of zfc, and assumes an external notion of a set which models zfc. I've also seen people use an external notion of set to talk about a formal system as a collection of strings corresponding to axioms of zfc.

Comment: Through this perspective, the key distinction in my head is the following. If I was given a set in my informal meta-theory, I can talk freely about all the elements in this collection, however, if I was only given a generation procedure, I can only talk about elements as I generate them. Is this essentially only an internal/external distinction? In other words, if I work internally within a model of zfc, I can only talk about elements as I generate them via the axioms, but I cannot know about them a priori as if I was looking externally at the set?

Comment: If you wish to understand finitists you'll have to give up your perspective. The practice of mathematics has no need for existence, philosophical commitments or ZFC with Tarski's model theory. Finitists think, moreover, that the latter is misleading or even harmful to said practice, and seek to replace it. God did not hand us down ZFC, or even set theory broadly, and command to conceptualize mathematics in terms of pregenerated(able) set models. You may be able to simulate some aspects of what they do in external/internal terms, but that is not what they are really getting at.

Comment: I see, I was trying to summarize my perspective hoping that you could tell me precisely which aspects differ from finitist or other philosophical perspectives in mathematics. I do agree that mathematics does not necessitate philosophical commitments, in the sense of the formalist perspective, unless you have something else in mind. I just want to understand the perspective you're putting forth and how exactly it differs from the one I'm used to. Is the difference in the fact that I'm designating a specific set of strings of symbols and a set that models axioms in the meta-theory?

Comment: There are two questions I have about this. Is working internally within the given set analogous to how finitists would think about it? I suggested that viewpoint because it seems that it would not be sensible to quantify over the entirety of the set when working internally, but that one can only use the given axioms describing the set and work up from the primitives which seems analogous to procedural generation. This seems to be a principal distinction which talking about generation yields, the fact that one does not quantify over the collection in totality.

Comment: Second, could I think of the generation procedure as we usually do in the informal meta-theory for example as constructing a certain sequence of morphisms? Namely, we do not necessarily have to talk about constructing the collection of all such morphisms before building such structures usually.

Comment: I did not mean formalism, which has commitments of its own, but what you called "being agnostic". I do not know what finitism "translated" into platonistic terms would look like, such "translations" typically distort. Restrictions on quantification are handled in [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory), and it is more complex than your description. There are internal/external perspective [interpretations of intuitionism using sheaves and topoi](http://www.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1974__15_2_157_0.pdf) that you may like, but I am not aware of something like that for finitism.

Comment: [Van den Berg's thesis](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.vandenberg3/thesis/mythesis.pdf) seems to focus on the inductive generation aspect of constructivism that you are concerned with and connects it to the topoi interpretations.

Comment: Got it, you're right in that the internal/external distinction I was thinking of was too naive since people always talk about quantifiers within a given model. The thesis you cited is interesting, but I believe I was trying to emphasize a more basic aspect of what you're talking about, namely the fact that he defines certain inductive notions within a category of sets to begin with. My understanding of what you're saying is that it is completely valid within an informal or formal, pre-specified theory, to have notions of algorithmic/generation on demand as being primitive.

Comment: In other words, am I incorrect in interpreting it as not necessarily having to work within a fixed domain of discourse? For instance, the prelude in the thesis talks about how traditional mathematics "discover mathematics" since they often discover truths by working in an a priori given set to begin with. The naive example I was trying to highlight is that in informal mathematics, we can talk about defining certain functions between sets without specifying a set/category of all such functions to begin with, and this seems akin to what I'm gleaning from your statements.

Comment: In other words, this naively seems more in line with "inventing mathematics". Lastly, given the above, it seems that discovery/invention is directly analogous to platonism/formalism. Perhaps I've been mistaken in believing that a formalist is necessarily taking strings from some pre-specified set, but instead is truly creating it via primitive generation procedures in a non-fixed domain of discourse.

Comment: Some of the above is simply a rephrasing of my question asking for verification of whether the key distinction for platonism is that I'm implicitly beginning with an external set of strings of symbols and sets that model axioms to begin with. Am I still missing something in my understanding summarized above?

Comment: There is [free logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/) for working without fixed domain of discourse, and recursive arithmetic and type theories take generating algorithms as primitives, one can use them in meta-theory. How formalists handle strings varies, Hilbert was a Kantian intuitionist in meta-theory, for example, but a formalist can even be a platonist as far as strings are concerned. What you describe is more like what a strict finitist would do. I do not think this maps into discovery/invention strictly speaking, but metaphorically perhaps.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I think that pretty much clarified everything. At the risk of sounding repetitive, although you probably implied this already, I was interpreting the notions of procedural generation of strings (of which we were discussing about a priori vs a posteriori notions) as equivalent to working in a non fixed domain of discourse which is also equivalent to taking such a procedural generation procedure as primitive rather than the outputs as primitive elements in some set.

Comment: After all, based on the discussion, it seems that one key distinction in working as a finitist is that we do not quantify over a fixed collection of elements (which would require an infinite number of steps in the generation procedure). Is this correct? And if it’s brief enough for you, it’d be great if you could explain a bit on how it doesn’t exactly match discovery/invention. You mentioned something about external/internal novelty before, but I didn’t completely grasp that statement.

Comment: Discovery/invention proper is something more advanced than generating new strings by an algorithm, whether they pre-existed or not. It concerns producing new objects and  systems to work with, which is a non-algorithmic process regardless of one's philosophy. It is over that that platonists and non-platonists argue what "producing" means exactly, whether it is more analogous to discovering new vistas in a landscape, inventing new contraptions for a machine, or breeding new plants in a garden.

Comment: Great, I see what you mean now. To conclude, could you verify my comments above regarding the equivalences? I just wanted to clarify my understanding on the relations among these restrictions.

Comment: It is closer than what we started with, but I am generally skeptical about "equivalence", and I am not a finitist, so what I say has limited value. I suspect there is a difference of opinion among them as to which formalization is best for the task, if any, and I doubt they would want to be pinned to any particular type of formalization. Brouwer objected to formal interpretations of intuitionism as such, for example.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Let me try to summarize my understanding now and let me know if this is accurate. Sorry for some of the rambling. I think ultimately the issue of not having a clear domain of discourse was what was bothering me from the beginning. This seems to be particularly exemplified by the notion of "generation of strings on demand" in which the actual output of strings are not pre-specified in some universe a priori but as we go, which doesn't seem to be how we conventionally do mathematics.

Comment: In other words, if I understand you correctly, the answer to the question of "what is the precise background in which we utilize a formal system" ranges from platonist (taking the set of all possible strings a priori) to perhaps the minimal commitment (taking the alphabet, rules, and co-catenation as god-given primitives (that necessarily exist platonistically themselves to avoid infinite regress) which operates in some unspecified background which could be fixed or dynamical).

Comment: If we were in a fixed background, I believe the only way we could talk sensibly about it is in modalizing the process to infinity and talking about all finite strings but without quantifying over the background. But I assume you're emphatically saying that it is not necessary to work in a fixed background, and that the latter minimal commitment described above is also valid, just working in some unspecified environment where the existence of objects is not specified, and where we just carry out these primitive operations.

Comment: I guess this goes back to your assertion of how a meta-theory is not necessary and that mathematics is built to be extremely flexible and to accommodate all kinds of philosophical stances. I suppose your point of a meta-theory not being necessary is not that we are denying the notion of a background in which we carry out primitive operations, which always exists in some sense by definition, but that we can be agnostic about it. And specifically, we can essentially do anything that the semantics of natural language allows as long as we do not contradict ourselves.

Comment: In conclusion, I guess this is essentially the distinction between a platonist and the opposite commitment, which I did not completely grasp from this perspective of using a formal system or that of a background thereof. A platonist would assume we necessarily have such a background to talk about pre-existing objects while (perhaps a) formalist is agnostic about the background. Sorry for the addition, but perhaps this explains my misconceptions better. I think a second source of my confusion was in conflating abstractly working in a formal system with a computer or turing machine carrying out

Comment: an algorithm in real life. We can assert that the product of such a procedure truly did not exist in the background (a specific time slice) a priori, and so it does not seem to be sensical to say we're building strings on demand in a background where the product of the objects do not exist. Here, I believe the response is precisely abstract vs physical existence which you stated. More succinctly, I was confused because in order to talk about this physical structure in totality, we would necessarily need a posteriori knowledge, namely working in a background which is a union over the histories.

Comment: I believe the last sentence in the above crucially captures the origin of the discussion, which supports a platonistic view of string generation. There's just one quick thing I wanted to verify. When you stated that my description of generating functions without reference to an overarching set was how a strict finitist would act, this is also how one would act when taking generating functions as primitive when using pra or type theory right? I just want to connect these two statements you were making.

Comment: To elaborate on this question, perhaps another perspective is that I'm asking how one would formalize the notion of generating strings without knowing their output a priori. For example, working in zfc we would define a function as a set starting from two established sets. I'm not familiar enough with pra, but does it allow us to formalize building an output using an established function and an input, working the other way? Please let me know if you have any comments on the above, I can also make it shorter as well.

Comment: My point was not that we can be agnostic about the "background", but that no such thing exists out there to be spelled out. We can only come up with some useful make belief that talks about it "as if". If formal system or natural language does not allow something we want, contradictions included, we revise them accordingly. How one interprets what they are doing in PRA or type theory is not dictated by the latter, one can be a finitist about it or platonize them like anything else. I am sure there are models of PRA with inputs and outputs, but why not work with function symbols directly.